# MySQL Cross table query join

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create an output table that is a combination of the two input tables, as shown below. Table 1 and table 2 are MySQL tables. Output is the desired table view.

[image]

Please hlep me to billd this output from table1 and table2 (mysql)

Comment: You mention php, so handle the display issue there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *conditional aggregation* with `UNION ALL` for this:

```sql
SELECT t1.acc_no, t1.name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t2.`date` = '2016-06-01' THEN amount END) AS '2016-06-01',
       SUM(CASE WHEN t2.`date` = '2016-06-02' THEN amount END) AS '2016-06-02',
       SUM(CASE WHEN t2.`date` = '2016-06-03' THEN amount END) AS '2016-06-03',
       SUM(amount) AS 'Total'
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.acc_no = t2.acc_no

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Total', null,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t2.`date` = '2016-06-01' THEN amount END) AS '2016-06-01',
       SUM(CASE WHEN t2.`date` = '2016-06-02' THEN amount END) AS '2016-06-02',
       SUM(CASE WHEN t2.`date` = '2016-06-03' THEN amount END) AS '2016-06-03',
       SUM(amount) AS 'Total'  
FROM table2
```

Comment: Conditional aggregation is not a good thing when dealing with dates, what if there are 30? `Pivot` is the correct solution here.

Comment: @sagi Unfortunately pivot is not available in MySQL (AFAIK).

Comment: Tnx & respect your answer, Also I want to know this. dates is not static. It's some loop. how to apply it this.

Comment: I think it's better to let PHP do the 'pivoting'. More flexible and scalable